# Why wouldn't this code run because of 1 line of code?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

Why would this code only run if i remove the `Total = 0` in the `while(Total != N)` loop and wouldn't run if i didn't remove it?
But the problem is i need to use that `total = 0` to be able to complete a certain test case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int N;

void Shift(long long B[]){
    int i;
    long long temp;
    temp = B[N - 1];
    for(i = N - 1; i > 0; i--){
        B[i] = B[i - 1];
    }
    B[0] = temp;
}

int main() {
    
    int j,i,Jumlah = 0,Total = 0;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    long long A[N],B[N];
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf(" %lld",&A[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf(" %lld",&B[i]);
        if(B[i] == A[i]) {
            Total++;
        }
    }
    while(Total != N) {
        Shift(B);
        Jumlah++;
        //Total = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if(A[i] == B[i]) {
                Total++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",Jumlah);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Test Case : N = 5 First Array = 1 2 5 3 4 Second Array = 5 1 4 2 3

Comment: I think it's because N = 0 at that line of code and hence the while loop ends before entering the nested for loop.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do, and what inputs do you test it with? As written and without other hidden assumptions, there is no guarantee that `Total` will ever `== N` in order to break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: in the test case i use the N is 4 and 7 but neither seems to work either

Comment: So the code supposed to count the minimum steps needed to make all of the second array allign with the first array

Test Case :
N = 5
First Array = 1 2 5 3 4
Second Array = 5 1 4 2 3

Comment: @FunGuyKawhi If the "*step*" is rotating the 2nd array by one position (which is what `Shift` does) then those two arrays can never completely "*align*". Try it on paper.

Comment: The purpose of the for loop inside of the while loop is to count wether all of the second array is alligned with the first array. And if the ammount of Total is equivalent to the N, i expected it to break the while loop becuase that means that all of the second array is alligned with the first array. And the Jumlah(which is Total in Indonesian) is the ammount of steps needed to allign the two set of array

Comment: @dxiv owhhhhh welp, my bad. guess i didn't read the problem properly. appreciate y'all.

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
    Total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if(A[i] == B[i]){
            Total++;
        }
    }
```

the variable `Total` will reach the value N if and **only if** the condition `A[i] == B[i]` is true for all values of `i`.

So when you wrap the code into a `while` statement like:

```
while (Total != N) {
    Total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        if(A[i] == B[i]){
            Total++;
        }
    }
}
```

you have an endless loop if `A[i] == B[i]` is false one or more times.

The shift-operation (i.e. `Shift(B);`) doesn't ensure that you will end in a situation where all elements in `B` equals all elements in `A`